# Javascript module returns undefined when using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

At the bottom of my `index.html` file I have the following.

```
<script src="/resources/js/require.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        require(['main'], function (main) {
            main.start();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This does indeed load the main.js file and waits for it to finish before calling `main.start()`. Now the problem is the `main` variable that is returned is not the module but it is instead `undefined`.

Here is the main.js:

```
define('/src/main', ['exports', '../screens/loginScreen'], function (exports, _loginScreen) {
    'use strict';

    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
        value: true
    });
    exports.start = undefined;

    function main() {};

    var start = exports.start = function start() {
        new _loginScreen.default().open();
    };
});
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

I tried having an actual return statement at the end of the main.js file. No matter what I return require still gives `undefined`.

Comment: You are not returning anything in your module?!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got the same error. The problem I think has to do with your `main.js` location. If it is on `src` folder on the root of your project, you need to pass its **relative** from the root of your project to `require`, like this:

```
require(['src/main'], function (main) {
   main.start();
});
```

Also, in your `main.js`, use **relative** path as well:

```
define('src/main', ['exports', '../screens/loginScreen'], function...
```

Comment: The javascript file is definitely being loaded by require so there can not be something wrong with the path.

Comment: Well, have you at least tried to user the same path `/src/main` both on `define` and `require`? Or maybe you could show more of your code so we can help more. Using the relative path really worked for me =/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your actual module is that it does not return anything, so it will just return `undefined`.

You need to wrap your module in a function and return this function, here's what you will need:

```
define('/src/main', ['exports', '../screens/loginScreen'], function(exports, _loginScreen) {
  'use strict';

  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });

  var Main = function Main() {

  }

  Main.start = exports.start = function start() {
    new _loginScreen.default().open();
  };

  return new Main();
});
```

Or if you want your module not to be the same instance shared in all pages and to be always instanciated with the `new` keyword, you can just return the `Main` function:

```
return Main;
```

Instead of returning an instance of it in `return new Main();`.